# [Déjà Dup]: Backup Failed

Tags: 20.04, software-center, backup, deja-dup

I'm trying to use **Déjà Dup Backup Tool** going with the **Ubuntu 20.04LTS** to backup my computer. But when I click "Backup Now" or let the software work as scheduled, an error notification appears: "Backup failed,
failed with an unknown error."

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 106, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 92, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1525, in main
    action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1175, in ProcessCommandLine
    globals.backend = backend.get_backend(args[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 225, in get_backend
    obj = get_backend_object(url_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 211, in get_backend_object
    return factory(pu)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/pydrivebackend.py", line 91, in __init__
    file_list = self.drive.ListFile({u'q': u"'Root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pydrive/apiattr.py", line 162, in GetList
    for x in self:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pydrive/apiattr.py", line 146, in __next__
    result = self._GetList()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 61, in _decorated
    self.auth.Authorize()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 523, in Authorize
    self.service = build('drive', 'v2', http=self.http)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 222, in build
    content = _retrieve_discovery_doc(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 273, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
    resp, content = http.request(actual_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 173, in new_request
    resp, content = request(orig_request_method, uri, method, body,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 280, in request
    return http_callable(uri, method=method, body=body, headers=headers,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1948, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1621, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1528, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1309, in connect
    sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
 socket.timeout: timed out
```

I've tried to update it on Ubuntu Software to the latest version, and re-do the backup every time I turn on my laptop. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04LTS, and the software goes along with my installation of Ubuntu. I want to backup the files to my Google Drive.
Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Could you update your question to include some additional information? (1) What verson of Ubuntu are you running? / (2) Is this a Snap/Flatpak/apt installation of Deja Dup? / (3) Where are you trying to write the backup file to? Local / Remote? This information may make it easier for someone to offer specific suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error too while backing up to Google Drive. The connection is timing out.

I'm not aware of a permanent solution for this, but a temporary workaround is to edit the default timeout setting for Duplicity, which Deja-Dup is a frontend for.

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/globals.py
```

In particular, you may want to edit the following lines:

```
# number of retries on network operations
num_retries = 5

# network timeout value
timeout = 30
```

I changed "timeout" from 30 to 200 and that fixed it for me.

Note that this will be overwritten whenever a new update for Duplicity comes out.

If the default values are stored somewhere else in the future, you can most likely find them using the command

```
sudo find / -iname *duplicity*
```

to search the whole system for any files or folders containing the word "duplicity".